# Examples of Families of Probability Distributions which are not Complete

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

By definition,a complete family of distributions $\{f_{\theta}(x):\theta \in \Theta\}$ (either pdfs or pmfs) has the property that for any measurable function $g$, then:

$E_{\theta}(g(X))=0 \space \space \forall \theta \in \Theta \Rightarrow P_{\theta}(g(X)=0)=1 \space \space \forall \theta \in \Theta$

However, in this case what would be an example of a family of distributions which is not complete? I saw some example related to the hypergeometric distribution but I'm not sure on how it goes. What would be a simpler example? (as well, what would it mean for a family of distributions to not be complete by negating the above statement?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take any family of (discrete or continuous) distributions all of which are symmetric (with respect to negation of $X$), and consider $g$ antisymmetric and non-zero. Then $E_{\theta}(g(X))=0 \space \space \forall \theta \in \Theta$ by symmetry, but $g(X)$ is generally non-zero.

See also [Showing a distribution is not complete for a parameter $\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102480).